# Is there a way in ruby to apply instance methods without repeating instance name

Tags: ruby

I have a class Foo with a large number of instance methods

```
class Foo
   def initalize(ary)
      @q = ary
   end

   def w
     q[0]
   end

   def x
     q[1]
   end

   ...
  private
  attr_reader :q
end
```

This class is used to implement mathematical algorithms involving operations on the qw, qx, etc.

I could implement the algorithms as follows

```
foo = Foo.new([1,2])
s = foo.w * foo.x + foo.x * foo.x
```

but some of the algorithms can require many lines and hundreds of terms like this, so repeating the `foo.` is tedious and gets in the way of readability. Is there a way in ruby so you can do something like this

```
foo = Foo.new
using foo do
  s = w * x + x * x
end
```

Comment: You could of course add an instance method `def f; w*x + x*x; end`, then `Foo.new([1,2]).f #=> 6` (as `w*x + x*x` is the same as `self.w*self.x = self.x*self.x`, since `self` is the default receiver).

Comment: Yes you can use `instance_eval` to do what you are looking for e.g. `s= foo.instance_eval { w * x + x * x}` [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/ModestDarkkhakiWheel#main.rb). The block will be executed in the context of the instance and will return the result of the block.

Comment: Thank you @engineersmnky, that works a treat. Do you want to do an answer so I can accept it, or will I?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have clarified the equation to make sure that many lines of equations are involved, so using your approach is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Your methods are called `qw` and `qx`, not `w` and `x`, so `foo.w` / `foo.x` won't work. Maybe it's just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way in ruby so you can do something like this...
>
> ```
> foo = Foo.new
> using foo do
>  s = w * x + x * x
> end
> ```

Yes ruby does provide a method, [`BasicObject#instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval), that allows you to execute a block of code in the context of a given instance of an object.  (`using` is a method that activates a [Refinement](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) which is a whole different discussion)

You can utilize `instance_eval` like so to achieve your goal:

```
class Foo 
  def w
    1 
  end
  def x 
    2 
  end 
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.instance_eval do
  w * x + x * x
end 
#=> 6
```

`instance_eval` does pass the receiver to the block however inside the block the implicit `self` is the receiver, allowing you to achieve your desired syntax.

There is one distinct difference to recognize between the implicit and explicit object within `instance_eval` which is that the one can implicitly call private methods however private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver (other than `self`) so the following occurs

```
class Foo
  def bar
    # self is not required just showing it is a valid receiver for the baz message
    self.baz 
  end
  private 
  def baz
    'private'
  end  
end 

foo = Foo.new 

foo.instance_eval {|f| f == self} #=> true
foo.instance_eval {|f| f.bar} #=> 'private'
foo.instance_eval {|f| f.baz} #=> NoMethodError (private method `baz' called...
foo.instance_eval {|f| baz} #=> 'private'
```